# 502 bad gateway on thin server, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, scalability, thin

I am making load test for app I am working on, on thin configuration behing nginx I get

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

when I send much more request my configuration can handle. On puma I get only 504 timeout.

Why thin refuses connection on high load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your thin config there is a parameter called `max_conns: <num connection>` and when there are more connections incoming then specified thin refuses new connections.

Comment: do you know if this option is also applicable to puma server?

Comment: this parameter is thin specific there is an equivalent for puma for sure but Im not familliar with it.